# Python Gevent Events Asynchronous Operation in more than 1 function on an Object

Tags: python, gevent

This is a piece of code I am running with its output:

```
import gevent
from gevent.event import Event


evt = Event()
In [45]: def op():
   ....:         global x
   ....:         while x<100:
   ....:                 x+=1
   ....:                 gevent.sleep(1)
   ....:                 evt.set()
   ....:

In [46]:

In [46]: def p():
   ....:         global x
   ....:         print 'changing x'
   ....:         x += 20
   ....:         print x
   ....:         evt.wait()
   ....:

In [47]: x = 10


In [48]: gevent.joinall([gevent.spawn(op),gevent.spawn(p)])
changing x
31

In [49]: x
Out[49]: 100

In [50]: x = 2

In [51]: gevent.joinall([gevent.spawn(op),gevent.spawn(p)])
changing x
23

In [52]: x
Out[52]: 100
```

I am trying to play around to figure out how gevent can be used to operate on some object(var,func,etc) at two different functions/methods? so it operates on one,
let us say in foo1() if the object is equal to some value then it goes to foo2() 
foo2 operates on it and when some value X is reached again it passes it back to foo1.

But I am unclear how to implement it. Could someone based on my description above give some simple practical code snippet so I could understand?
Thanks in advance!